# How to kill all incoming SSH connections?

Tags: ssh, python

I am developing a driver to remote control a Raspberry Pi over SSH. While this connection is active the RPi displays some message on it's touchscreen. So far everything works just fine.

The Raspberry Pi runs on Raspbian 8 (jessie).

Now, I want to be able to end the SSH connection on the RPi via some button click event. As far as I know, an incoming SSH connection can be terminated by getting the corresponding process' ID and killing it. On said button click event I want to kill all incoming sessions. Is there a shell command or Python module that does that for me? Extracting all running SSH connection's process IDs seems a bit to much work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using Raspberry Pi OS or Ubuntu? Which version? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1382471/edit) and add these information.

Comment: Done. @user68186

Comment: This question should be asked here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com or here https://unix.stackexchange.com/